# about ostream and how to use in the main function

Tags: c++, c++builder

I had to write a function which `binary_print(outstream& outs,unsigned int a)`
but when i write a test file for that function it says error.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{ 
    unsigned int d;
    std::cout<<"Enter any positive decimal number:";
    std::cin>>d;
         std::cout<<"Binary of your number is "<<binary_print(cout,d);//<<endl;

     std::cout<<'\n';}
}
```

errors:

> testfile_rec.cpp:18:60: error: no match for 'operator<<' in
>   'std::operator<< [with _Traits =
>   std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream&)(& std::cout)),
>   ((const char*)"Binary of your number is ")) <<
>   binary_print(((std::ostream&)(& std::cout)), d)' ostream:108:7: note:
>   candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:117:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ios_type&)) [with _CharT =
>   char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ios_type =
>   std::basic_ios] ostream:127:7: note:
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base&
>   (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits =
>   std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:165:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:169:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:173:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream.tcc:91:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with
>   _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits] ostream:180:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int)
>   [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits,
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type =
>   std::basic_ostream] ostream.tcc:105:5: note:
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits] ostream:191:7: note:
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with
>   _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type =
>   std::basic_ostream] ostream:200:7: note:
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with
>   _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type =
>   std::basic_ostream] ostream:204:7: note:
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned
>   int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits,
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type =
>   std::basic_ostream] ostream:209:7: note:
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_ostream_type&
>   std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT =
>   char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:213:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:221:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream:225:7: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_ostream_type = std::basic_ostream] ostream.tcc:119:5: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, *Traits>::*_streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   *Traits>::*_streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf]

Comment: I would normally be a good idea to include the error in your questions.

Comment: What is the error? What does the function `binary_print` return?

Comment: error: 'out' was not declared in this scope

Comment: and it binary_print return binary number

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful here.

Comment: @ForestHill The code you posted doesn't make use of anything called `out` so either the code you posted is different from what you're using or the error you posted is different from the error you got. In programing correct spelling is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the binary representation of the given integer, then easy way is to use `std::bitset` as:

```
#include<bitset> //include this so as to use std::bitset

unsigned int input;
std::cin >> input;
std::cout << std::bitset<32>(input) << std::endl;
```

This will print 32-bit binary representation of the value stored in `input`. It is even better to write this as:

```
#include <bitset>   //for std::bitset
#include <climits>  //for CHAR_BIT

std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof(input)>(input) << std::endl;
```

Now you can wrap this functionality in a function as:

```
template<typename T>
void binary_print(std::ostream & out, const T & input)
{ 
   out << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)>(input) << std::endl;
}
```

Test code:

```
int main() {
        int input;
        std::cin >> input;
        binary_print(std::cout, input);        //print int-representation
        binary_print(std::cout, (short)input); //print short-representation
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000010001000010100
0010001000010100
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/OQU6F

Comment: Deleted comment thread, as you guys have updated the question/answer appropriately.  Start over from there. =)

Answer (score 1):

`cout` is an object of `class ostream` that represents the standard output stream.

Your function incorrecly takes the parameter of type `outstream`. The function declaration:

```
binary_p(outstream& outs,unsigned int a)
```

should be:

```
binary_p(std::ostream& outs,unsigned int a)
         ^^^^^^^^
```

Also, You need to tell your program the namespace in which `cout` and `cin` are defined.
Do:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

In your c++ file.
I am not sure this is the only error because You haven't posted the actual error in the Question.

Comment: sorry it would be binary_p(ostream& outs,unsigned int a)

Comment: that was typo and it is fixed in the program

Comment: +1 for your Psychic Skills.
@ForestHill: Please remember [to "accept" this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @ForestHill: Check the updated answer that shall fix your `error: 'out' was not declared in this scope` problem.

Comment: using "using std::cout;
using std::cin;" ?

Comment: using std::cout;
using std::cin;  if I use those should I use "using namespace std;"  andd what should I write for function calling -binary_print(cout,d);

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be using it inline with your ostream `<<` calls.

```
cout << "Binary of your number is ";
binary_print(cout,d);
cout << '\n';
```

Edit: and indeed the error that you've posted now shows that the compiler can't figure out what `operator<<` to use with the result of your call to binary_print(). The error basically says "error: no match for '`operator<<`' in `std::cout<<"Binary of your number is "<<binary_print(cout,d);` and then lists all the alternatives it tried to match.

Comment: Isn't this the whole purpose of returning the output stream?

Comment: then error is "undefined reference to `binary_print(std::ostream&, unsigned int)'"

Comment: @AndréCaron I don't think you generally call `operator<<` with an ostream on the right side (i.e., `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,ostream& rhs)`) which is what would happen if binary_print returned an ostream& and it was used inline.

Comment: @ForestHill Your question mentions `binary_print` and `binary_p`. You'll have to use whichever one your code actually defines.

Comment: that was typo.It should be binary_print

Comment: @bames53: the call to `binary_print()` does not receive an `ostream&` as a right hand side argument, it receives an `unsigned int`.  Check OP's code snippet.

Comment: @AndréCaron Yes, but consider: `cout << foo(cout,int)` First `foo(cout,int)` will be called. Second, `operator<<` will be called with `cout` on the left hand side _and the result of `foo()` on the right hand side_. If the result of `foo()` is `ostream&` then `operator<<` will be called with `ostream&` on the right hand side.

Comment: @bames53: indeed... sorry about that!